# I have a JSON file attached below and i want to print it in the console, currently i am using xcode 4.4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

```
companies:[
{
  "name":"APPLE",
  "id":"1",
  Departments:[
  {
     "name":"Designing",
     "id":"1.1",
     Employees:[
     {
     "name":"Ramesh",
     "id":"1.1.1",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
     {
     "name":"Suresh",
     "id":"1.1.2",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
      {
     "name":"Mukesh",
     "id":"1.1.3",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     }
     ]
     },


     {
     "name":"Developing",
     "id":"1.2",
     Employees:[
     {
     "name":"Ram",
     "id":"1.2.1",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
     {
     "name":"Sam",
     "id":"1.2.2",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
      {
     "name":"Dham",
     "id":"1.2.3",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     }
     ]
     },

     {
     "name":"Testing",
     "id":"1.3",
     Employees:[
     {
     "name":"Rocky",
     "id":"1.3.1",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
     {
     "name":"Jockey",
     "id":"1.3.2",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
      {
     "name":"Sockey",
     "id":"1.3.3",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     }
     ]
     }
     ]
     },




{
  "name":"GOOGLE",
  "id":"2",
  Departments:[
  {
     "name":"Designing",
     "id":"2.1",
     Employees:[
     {
     "name":"Ramesh",
     "id":"2.1.1",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
     {
     "name":"Suresh",
     "id":"2.1.2",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
      {
     "name":"Mukesh",
     "id":"2.1.3",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     }
     ]
     },


     {
     "name":"Developing",
     "id":"2.2",
     Employees:[
     {
     "name":"Ram",
     "id":"2.2.1",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
     {
     "name":"Sam",
     "id":"2.2.2",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
      {
     "name":"Dham",
     "id":"2.2.3",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     }
     ]
     },

     {
     "name":"Testing",
     "id":"2.3",
     Employees:[
     {
     "name":"Rocky",
     "id":"2.3.1",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
     {
     "name":"Jockey",
     "id":"2.3.2",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     },
      {
     "name":"Sockey",
     "id":"2.3.3",
     "salary":"4lakhs"
     }
     ]
     }
     ]
     }
     ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a file in bundle (as it wasnt clear from the question), you can read the file with following code:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOU_FILE_NAME" ofType:@"txt"];

NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

then print it to console using:

```
NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
```

Comment: thanq sir, it's really help full........

Comment: how to display it in a table....?

Comment: You need to parse the data first into displayable/usable form, as Rajneesh071 mentioned, you can use [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) for parsing.

Create entities for the data you need and store the data using entity objects.

Answer (score 0):

Parse using [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) and then NSLog it

```
        NSString *replycode=[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"replyCode"];
        NSLog(@"Reply = %@",replycode);
```